# Oracle : large Number getting converted scientific notation (40 digits) on concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

Oracle converts Number to string on concatenation or moving it to_char.

Example:

```
select value from tab;
value
9076725748515642018090620180906173606980000000000000000000000000000000000000000

select RPAD(value,LENGTH(value)+1,chr(135)) from tab;

RPAD(value,LENGTH(value)+1,chr(135))
9.0767257485156420180906201809061736E+78‡
```

Intended result

```
9076725748515642018090620180906173606980000000000000000000000000000000000000000‡
```

Comment: What data type is value?

Comment: @DivyeKapoor . . . I don't understand the question.  Your query has no concatenation.

Comment: In the first case your client is displaying the number natively; in the second case (whether you use `rpad` as you've shown, or concatenation as you said) it's being converted to a string (implicitly), and it's using scientific notation because that's the only way [to fit the value in 40 characters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html): "If you omit fmt, then n is converted to a VARCHAR2 value exactly long enough to hold its significant digits." You can't format a number to an 80-digit string though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe PL/SQL can help you. You can try below script.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test123 (p_number NUMBER) return VARCHAR2
IS
    v_no VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
     'select '''||p_number||'''||CHR(135) '||
      ' from dual'
      INTO v_no;
    RETURN v_no;
END;
/

SELECT TEST123(9076725748515642018090620180906173606980000000000000000000000000000000000000000) 
FROM DUAL;

OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9076725748515642018090620180906173606980000000000000000000000000000000000000000‡
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am creating a key and can only use SQL as it is being called form Qlikview.

Comment: select test123(818471545454540201702142017021408021756000000000000000000000000000000000000009009099) from dual; --- gave me 818471545454540201702142017021408021756000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000‡ ; digits after position 40 changed to 0

Comment: I see. I tried it also, same thing happens when I run the query. I have no idea why it behaves like that. How about if test123 function will have 3 number parameters and you will only pass numbers with a length of 40? Can it solved your problem? Anyways, I tried to run this query,
select 9076725748515642018090620180906173606981||9076725748515642018090620180906173606981||9076725748515642018090620180906173606981
  from dual;, Oracle displays the 120 characters.